# How to cast objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have this object:

```
{
  "id": "Test",
  "firstname": "Test",
  "lastname": "Test",
  "age": 83
}
```

but i want to return object only with this value:

```
{
    "id": "Test"
}
```

how to cast first object to another one with using TS/NodeJS?

Comment: Is your data in an array?

Comment: Make a new object and include only the properties from the original object that you want.

Comment: @MarcusCantu I have no array

Comment: @Pointy Is there a better way, eq. with using interface or dto?

Comment: Why would you need something better than something as simple as making a new object with a property or two in it?

Comment: @Pointy I think that this is a bad practice when we have a so many properties to include into another object

Comment: Your question is about **one property**. If you have a question that is substantially different, you should ask the **real** question.

Comment: Before sending this post, I thought about it and decided that it was logical and no one will have a problem with it ...

Answer (score 2):

You could write a function like this that uses a [`property accessor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) to only return the `id` of the object:

```js
let data = { id: 'Test', firstname: 'Test', lastname: 'Test', age: 83, };

function trimToId(data) {
  return { id: data.id };
}

console.log(trimToId(data))
```

If you wanted to make this more concise you could use an [`arrow function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) with [`destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
let data = { id: 'Test', firstname: 'Test', lastname: 'Test', age: 83 };

const trimToId = ({ id }) => ({ id });

console.log(trimToId(data));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is a Utility Type called Partial. You can find the documentation [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html).

```js
interface FirstObject {
  id: string;
  firstname: string;
  lastname: string;
  age: number;
}

const firstObject: FirstObject = {
  "id": "Test",
  "firstname": "Test",
  "lastname": "Test",
  "age": 83
};

const secondObject: Partial<FirstObject> = {
  "id": "Test"
};
```

Comment: the underscore breaks your explanation [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGLCgZzAeQEYBWECYyA3gLABQyywAJgFzLZSgDmA3NbTBtiDgBbCM1YduNZABs4A4aJZg2ILj2Rx2ikAFcheaJIC+1aggD2IbMj5ZchYmGbo7+IiWQBecuoBEDX2ZfABUIbF8AGj9beRFA5BCwsEi-WViIeMTwqKlfTQzmAA4AZmojSTNLa0xiS3o3R2YABTgoMGA4aQAeF2wGkgA+Lx9cgKDQ8LLOIA) otherwise the only answer that addresses the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
function foo(input) {
   return {id: input.id}; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is just as you presented it:

```
const object = {
  id: "Test",
  firstname: "Test",
  lastname: "Test",
  age: 83
}

const newObject = {id: object.id}
//or
const {id} = object;//destructuring
const newObject = {id};
```